# RMI: How to set socket timeout for the vm that make the remote methods call?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I have this case where the RMI client code invokes a remote method that is supposed to return a `byte[]`, for one reason or another during the execution of this method on the server side, a really bad thing might happen such as the server going down or whatever..., in this case I end up with a stuck thread (with a stack trace as below):

```
ool-4-thread-1" #71 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001a4f6000 nid=0xa30 runnable [0x000000001f7fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000759b19aa8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.generatePDF(Unknown Source)
    at com.etq.reliance.pdf.PDFUtils.generatePDFRemotely(PDFUtils.java:147)
...
```

What I'am trying to achieve here is to handle this case, I thought that I could easily solve this problem by using the one of the following RMI properties:

```
sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout
```

I even tried [All the other RMI properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html#readTimeout), but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how to set some sort of a read timeout?

Comment: `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout` should do it, if set correctly at the client JVM.

Comment: This property is already set as:  `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=5000`, but it does not seem to have any effect. Could this be related to the Java version I' am using (1.8.0_25)?

Comment: It's described in your link as '1.4 and later', so it should work with 1.8. Are you setting it at the client JVM? and before you execute any remote calls (including Registry calls)? RMI system properties tend to be only read once.

Comment: Yes, I am setting the property directly in Tomcat's Java Options, since the client is actually a web app.

Comment: Can you (a) check that Tomcat hasn't set it to something else before your first RMI call? and (b) provide a log with `-Dsun.rmi.client.logCalls=true` around that call?

Comment: (a)no its not being set anywhere else, I even defined a new environment variable "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS", and I've set the property there. I checked the tomcat log and this line was there `INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=5000`

Comment: (b) What do you expect to see? I did not notice any difference in the log after setting `-Dsun.rmi.client.logCalls=true`. I took another thread dump after setting those properties and  stack trace is still the same.

Comment: I expected to see the client's call log. It is looking as though these system properties are simply not being set.

Comment: You are right, seems that the properties were not being set, I still don't know why, but when I tried on another machine it worked. Thanks for your help.